# How can i render PDF which is saved in database as binary data using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

I am working on an HTML website. PDF file is saved in database (MS SQL Server 2008 R2) as binary data. This need to be fetched and displayed in a webpage using jQuery. I tried using object tag in HTML. But PDF is not getting displayed.

Can we convert binary data to pdf format using jQuery/javaScript?

```js
$('#pdf-container').html('<object type="application/pdf" src="sample.pdf"></object>');
```

```html
<div id="pdf-container" />
```

Comment: What are you using server-side to return the binary stream as a file?

Comment: Server side coding is done in dot net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some how the following code seems to work:

```
$("#pdf-container").html('<iframe type="text/html" src="sample.pdf"></iframe>')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use anyone of this approach:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306654

http://aspguy.wordpress.com/2008/06/08/download-a-file-into-client-with-aspnet-20/
 http://www.xefteri.com/articles/show.cfm?id=8

Change the Response.ContentType to the correct type of content being streamed, which you can do by examining the extension of the file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I need to solve this issue using jQuery or javaScript. I am not supposed to change DotNet components.

Comment: hello, in your object you are missing the Data attrbute that is the id of that pdf file, ex: data=\"{0}{1}\" .Please try with it and check

Comment: After mentioning Data attribute also, the PDF file is not getting displayed. I have changed code as: <object type="application/pdf" data="sample.pdf" />